# Dynamically calling upon similar objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I apologize in advance for the title, but I had no idea how to word what I'm trying to ask (and if a similar question was asked before, I wouldn't have known how to search for it).
So I have four very similar objects in my program, and as such I have differentiated them like so:

```
var person1Object = {
    foo: [],
    bar: []
}
var person2Object = {
    foo: [],
    bar: []
}
var person3Object = {
    foo: [],
    bar: []
}
var person4Object = {
    foo: [],
    bar: []
```

as well as a variable that counts 1 through 4 through another function when a button is pressed, like so:

```
var count = 1;
function count() {
    if (count < 4) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 1;
    }
}
$("#button").on("click", function () { count(); });
```

I am trying to do something that would look like this:

```
person+count+Object.foo.push("some value");
person+count+Object.bar.push("some other value");
```

But when I do that, the console says (and I'm assuming rightfully so) `person is not defined`.

I have tried using an array like so:

```
var personObject = [person1Object, person2Object, person3Object, person4Object]
personObject[count].foo.push("some value");
```

but that does not work either. Also, I would like to avoid if statements if I can.

How would I manipulate these objects without simply using a bunch of if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access objects with dynamic names like that via the window object (in a browser anyway).

So something like this should work:

```
window['person'+count+'Object'].foo.push("some value");
window['person'+count+'Object'].bar.push("some other value");
```

if you needed to do it in node, you would do the same thing but use `global` instead, so:

```
global['person'+count+'Object'].foo.push("some value");
global['person'+count+'Object'].bar.push("some other value");
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! I was afraid I was going to need to add a bunch of if statements, but this fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple array? (it runs from 0 to 4)

```js
var person = Array.apply(null, { length: 4 }).map(function () {
    return {
        foo: [],
        bar: []
    };
});

//access
person[1].foo.push(42);
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(person, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: I tried using an array but it refused to work for me for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The first approach fails because you need to know the scope and address it with a string instead. I assume this code is launched in browser and at top level. It should look like

```
for(var i=0; i < 4; i++){
   window['person'+i+'Object'].foo.push("some value");
}
```

However this is not good as it is dependant on `window`, you can't move the code into some function, and can't change names.

Second approach is the right way to do. I.e. put similar objects into array to process them in a cycle. The problem experienced is caused by same name of function and variable. Name variable `index` and will work